# Looking for a software development term describing the effort it takes to learn a new skill/framework

Tags: single-word-requests, business-language, software

I want to say that the framework is designed for rapid development, maximal portability, and **minimal [time-to-figure-out-how-to-use-it].**

The idea is that it's very intuitive, so you don't need to spend a lot of time sifting through documentation to get started.

Time-to-proficiency? Learning curve?

Is there a single word that means this?

Comment: I'd to with *learning curve*. That's short enough and readily understood.

Comment: You could use _minimal familiarisation (or familiarization)_ if you really needed a single word, but even that would be better as _minimal familiarisation requirement_ or _ minimal familiarisation time_

Comment: Usually people say that it's *intuitive* or *accessible* or *it has an intuitive interface* and it's *designed so you can get up to speed quickly.*  Or that it's *self-explanatory*.

Answer (score 1):

[Learning Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_curve) is a common term for the time required to learn something, when compared with the experience gained, though it's not a single word.